# Why does the same timestamp represent different points in an MP3 in different media players?

Tags: audio, mp3, codec

I have an MP3 file that's 11 minutes long. When I jump to, say, 6:15 in the song in some media players (VLC, the web browser), that timestamp represents a different point in the song than in other media players (Windows Media Player or DAWs like Reaper and Audacity). That is, the same point in the song is at 6:15 in some players and at 6:25 or so in others.

In all players, the song still seems to be the full 11 minutes. It's not clear to me where the timing difference emerges.

What could cause this discrepancy? Is a codec issue? An issue with the MP3? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the program is seeking through the mp3 file it may not be getting the right time. Mp3 files do not have timestamps data frames so a variable bitrate (VBR) file may not be able to easily calculate the number of data frames to get to a particular time in the file.

A constant bitrate (CBR) file at least has a fixed amount of audio "time" per data frame so you can at leasy calculate how many frames will get you to the rough time you are seeking to, within approximately 26ms for 44.1kHz audio, so you're reasonably likely to get the time correct.

For VBR files though you can have somewhat random lengths of time per frame. Quiet sounds or constant frequencies may compress better and take up less of a data frame resulting in fewer overall frames to get to a specific time in other words a frame of data might be 36ms instead of 26ms. Other sounds may take up a higher bitrate resulting in shorter time for frames.

VBR files might have a tag that tells you the "average" bitrate, but being an average across a file doesn't make seeking within that file particularly accurate.

What you end up with overall is that for VBR files you can no longer use a fixed calculation to get to a specific time in the file. To get to a precise time you have to fully decode the entire file and seek through the decoded output.

As a result you can end up with some programs seeking accurately through the file based on the processed data, and some programs that simply saying "well the average says this so if I calculate the average time per frame then it needs this many frames to get to that time".

The result is that some programs may end up at a different "time" in the file.

More information is at
[Stack Overflow: Precise seek in MP3 files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53747530/278545)